# ASP.NET "Sessions Timed Out" Counter (perfmon.exe)

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory, session-state

I'm currently load testing an ASP.NET application. I'm charging with 500 users on the app, 
and while it's running I'm checking, in a perfmon.exe console, the "Sessions Actives" and "Sessions Timed Out" counters on the web server.

In my web.config, the session timeout is 3 minutes (for test's purpose).

So as the test goes, the "Sessions Actives" counter stays on about 900 active sessions, which I assume is normal because of the 500 active users and about 400 other whose sessions haven't timed out yet.

But when I look at the "Session Timed Out" counter, it countinuously increases. It just goes down gradually when the load test finishes.

What is this counter exactly? As I understand it, it's the deprecated sessions that have not been yet cleaned up (by the garbage collector?) and are still using memory.

Since our application is using a *huge* ammount of memory, I'm trying to find exactly *where* is that memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter seems to be indicating what is happening. i.e. As the sessions that are active start up, the counter for active goes to the right number.. and at some point they start to die down and they trigger the session time out to increase (i.e. the sessions that are summarily dismissed by the ASP.NET infrastructure). I am not sure what you are expecting to see. I recommend reading the chapters, [15](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647791.aspx), [16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647788.aspx) and [17](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx) of the [Improving .NET Application Performance and Scalability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649152.aspx) book. They are pretty enlightening in this regard.

Comment: I fact, what I really need to know, is if these timed out sessions are still using memory. Thanks for the link, I'll check it today.

Comment: Well, after testing some more, this timer does not go down until the application pool is restarted (like, iisreset).[br]But still it seems that the timed out session are not cleaned up (the memory is not freed) until my loadtest ends.

Comment: Do you have any RCW content running in the session? for e.g. do you have any legacy COM objects being accessed and stored in the session? I have seen them cause load to stay high. It also feels like you might want to look at other counters to figure out the specific thing that is eating memory. I have used the chapters I have mentioned above to give me pointers on where it is being held. Specifically, the GC counters are of great help (gen0, gen1 and gen2).

Comment: I mainly store strings and ints in session, no COM object at all... looking at the results of my test, the sum of gen 0, 1, 2 and large object heap size is 592Mb. But, my memory goes down from 3500Mb to 588Mb. Kind of annoying. And GC is working at an average of 22%, with some peaks at 80%. Maybe memory is occupied by unmanaged objects, but I dont see how to find. Well, thanks a lot for the help.